# ef power tools beta 4 not showing entityframework context menu

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, ef-power-tools

I have installed entity framework power tools beta 4 but can't see the entity framework in context menu after right clicking on  project.

I have Visual Studio 2013 Web Express Edition installed. Please advise if someone faced a similar issue.

Thanks,
Krishna.

Comment: Have you checked if it is disabled in your Tools->Extension Manager?

Comment: in extension manager section i can see only "microsoft asp.net and web tools " and its showing it with disable,uninstall buttons and both the buttons are disabled..

Comment: Sounds like the install didn't take. Try installing again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can install Power Tools for Entity Framework

Go  Tools--> Extensions and Updates

[image]

click at the Online tab then

type in Search box

> Entity Framework Power Tools

you will get it here you can download and install. 
After installing it restart Visual Studio and now you can use it.
To Check
Right click at your solution you can see see Entity Framework in the list displayed.